# WebBrowser control inside IE

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer, com, activex

I have a .NET ActiveX/COM Object which has a WebBrowser control (among other controls such has buttons, etc) inside it.

This object seems to load fine, the buttons are displayed and working but, for some reason, the WebBrowser control doesn't show up!

Is there some limitation for this in IE (e.g., is IE afraid of something recursive, etc.)? Is there a way that I can overcome it?

Thanks in advance,

Zubrowka

Comment: You should rethink your design. An ActiveX hosted by a browser that contains a webbrowser control... Really?

Comment: Agreed. ActiveX in the browser == asking for trouble, even without the design WTF you're describing here.

Comment: This is a technical question, not really a design question. I'm developing a plugin for an application with more than 10 years and I don't have many other options left. So, coming back to the basic of my question, can I do it or not?

Comment: i'd recommend you reverse engineer the app and rewrite the activex porting of it in javascript, java, or silverlight depending on what it does.

Comment: Can you post test code somewhere that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireBreath has a library called WebView that does this; I've tested it both in NPAPI based browsers and in ActiveX and it works just fine. There are many reasons why you may want to do this.

Since I don't know what you're doing, I can't tell you what you're doing wrong... but I can show you the source code that FireBreath uses to do it:

https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/libs/WebView/Win/WebViewWin.cpp

This is in C++, but you might be able to find something useful from it.  I don't use .net in the browser -- too much overhead -- but theoretically the same principles should apply.